# Mogenerator and setPrimitiveType

Tags: reserved-words, mogenerator

I have about a half dozen tables coming from a legacy web server. These tables all have a "type" column. I need to keep these column names in sync at the app level.

Using mogenerator, the base class it creates dutifully generates a **setPrimitiveType** attribute. Well Apple doesn't like this method and rejected our app.

Is it possible to change mogenerator to not create certain methods of the model's attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to fine-tune what mogenerator creates.  This is done by updating the entries in the templates for the machine files.  For example, the following lines can be commented out from the machine.h template file.

```
- (void)setPrimitive<$Attribute.name.initialCapitalString$>:(<$Attribute.objectAttributeType$>)value;
```

```
- (void)setPrimitive<$Attribute.name.initialCapitalString$>Value:(<$Attribute.scalarAttributeType$>)value_;
```

The former is the regular accessor.  The latter is the scalar accessor and it could even be renamed if desired.

However, do notice that the Core Data framework and not mogenerator are generating the basic accessors as pointed out by the Apple Docs [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html):

> For example, given an entity with an attribute firstName, Core Data automatically generates firstName, setFirstName:, primitiveFirstName, and setPrimitiveFirstName:. Core Data does this even for entities represented by NSManagedObject. To suppress compiler warnings when you invoke these methods, you should use the Objective-C 2.0 declared properties feature, as described in “Declaration.”

Comment: Yes the templates are where to make the modifications. However, if my memory serves me, we were having problems with attribute names with first letter being capitalized. We renamed all the attributes and then did some pre and post rest processing.

Comment: For what its worth, mogenerator seems to have been modified to specifically avoid this situation. As of today, however, you'll have to pull the latest HEAD from the website and compile it yourself, however.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 'type' keyword.
My solution was manually creating and implementing methods like

```
- (NSNumber *)primitiveType;
- (void)setPrimitiveType:(NSNumber *)value_;
```